# When do Stored Procedures get deleted / dropped implicitly?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Does the stored procedures get deleted / dropped if the tables they are referring to are dropped?

Does the stored procedures get deleted / dropped if the database they are referring to are dropped?

What other ways that might result in deleting / dropping the store procedures beside the explicit call of `DROP PROCEDURE` (if any exist)?

I'm testing this on DB2 Version 9.7

Comment: `Does the stored procedures get deleted / dropped if the tables they are referring to are dropped?`  No, they do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the stored procedures get deleted / dropped if the tables they
>   are referring to are dropped?

NO they are not.

> Does the stored procedures get deleted / dropped if the database they
>   are referring to are dropped?

Yes if you delete the database then everything inside it is deleted.

> What other ways that might result in deleting / dropping the store
>   procedures beside the explicit call of DROP PROCEDURE (if any exist)?

No there is no other way except to either delete/drop the procedure explicitly or delete the database.